# Haskell shift right

Tags: haskell, shift

Still working on trying to implement Boyer Moore algorithm.
Due in a few hours and I can't get this pesky shift part working.
It works if there is a 1:1 match i.e 
boyerMoore "hello" "hello"

but it doesn't work for "howareyou" "are"

I'm almost certain my problem lies within the boyMoore area with the ifs.

I'm pretty sure that it's something in the boyerMoore function itself and not the shift methods. Just wondering if I am calling it in the right way or if I am over looking something? Appreciate any help.
Also sorry for asking so many questions today, just want this assignment over and done with as it is our last one.

```
boyerMoore :: String -> String -> Bool
boyerMoore [] _ = False
boyerMoore mainString patternString =
    let 
    patternLength = (length patternString)
    position = getPosition patternString (take patternLength(mainString))
    in if (mainString == patternString)
        then True
        else
                if position > -1
                then boyerMoore (patternString) (drop position(mainString))
                else boyerMoore (patternString) (drop patternLength(mainString))

getPosition :: String -> String -> Int
getPosition [] _ = -1
getPosition mainString patternString = shift patternString mainString (length patternString)

shift :: String -> String -> Int -> Int
shift [] _ _ = -1
shift textString patternString lengthVariable =
    if (last patternString) == (last textString)
    then lengthVariable - (length patternString)
    else shift (init patternString) textString lengthVariable
```

Comment: I don't know the actual algorithm you are trying to implement, but can you tell what `shift` is supposed to do maybe with an example.

Comment: @ Satvik The best way I can show what it is supposed to do is if you go here: http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~jgirata3/boyermoore/

That shows the algorithm at work, and shift should be shifting the elements like it does in that example

Comment: I read the algorithm at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm and from what I saw I don't think you have implemented the actual algorithm. Maybe you need to read the algorithm again.

Comment: @ do you think? some of my friends said their shift was similar and it worked for them

Comment: Somebody needs to say it at some time, so here goes: The Boyer/Moore algorithm is **not** a good choice for linked lists of characters. Its strength of being able to skip characters, and its backward moving comparisons require fast indexed access. For a linked list, you need an algorithm that only moves forward, Knuth-Morris-Pratt is a good choice. The additional comparisons it may need over BM are more than compensated by avoiding the bookkeeping necessary for BM.

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't describe the Boyer/Moore algorithm, by the way. Only part of it [I think it's Boyer/Moore/Horspool].

Comment: And if it is important that you implement Boyer-Moore, it makes more sense to use `Text` from `Data.Text` rather than `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Your final equation for `boyerMoore` starts

```
boyerMoore mainString patternString =
```

but the recursive calls at the end both have the form

```
boyerMoore patternString (drop foo mainString)
```

My knowledge of Boyer-Moore is rusty, but I doubt you want to swap `patternString` with `mainString` like that.

Secondly, I think you may be confusing the *last()* function on [the page you link to](http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~jgirata3/boyermoore/) with Haskell's [`last`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3alast) function. `last` gives back the final element of the list you give it, whereas *last()*, despite the notation, takes two arguments: a character to look for, and the pattern string to look in.